# How can an R+ tree extend its coverage?

Tags: ds.data-structures

In [the original article on R+ tree](http://www.cs.cmu.edu/~christos/PUBLICATIONS.OLDER/vldb87.pdf), `Algorithm Insert` recursively searches for all leaf nodes that overlap the given input rectangle `IR` and adds `IR` to each of those leaves. But what if part of `IR` is not covered by any existing leaf? How will that part ever be indexed?

Comment: I assume you just enlarge the rectangles associated with each node on the path of these leafs to the root, so that they cover the new rectangles completely. I think there are various heuristics in splitting leafs and redistributing rectangles  to try and counter this. Thats the nice thing about R^*+/--trees - they dont panic if there is some overlap.